# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPExcel_Style_Protection' not found on laravel

Tags: laravel

In laravel I want protect cell, but a get error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PHPExcel_Style_Protection' not found, I use MaatWebsite class. this my code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
class ExportExcellDaftarhadirController extends Controller
{
Excel::create('exsport', function($excel) {
$excel->sheet('Daftar', function($sheet){
$sheet->getProtection()->setPassword('password');
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);                                
$sheet->getStyle('A12:B20')->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);

    $sheet->loadView('export_excell.daftarhadirujian')
     });
    })->export('xls');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `\PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED` instead of `PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the properly-namespaced path to PHPExcel_Style_Protection.  I don't know the path as I'm unfamiliar with the Maatwebsite library but, as PHP is currently warning you, PHPExcel_Style_Protection isn't found within the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace.

If you're unfamiliar with namespaces, php's [namespace documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) should help clarify their purpose and usage.